# Concatenating hex bytes in C

Tags: c, hex

I am trying to concatenate 4 hex bytes together and am running into some trouble.

I have a 32 bit number represented as 4 hex bytes (`x`). I have another 4 bit number I taking the 2's complement as (`twos_complement`) and then turning that into a hex representation (`ne`). THEN I want to sub the single byte (`ne`) in as the third byte of the original 32 bit number (`x`). Here is what I have so far:

```
unsigned replace_byte(unsigned x, unsigned char b) {
    unsigned new;
    unsigned int twos_complement;
    twos_complement = (~b) +1;

unsigned int ne = (twos_complement & 0xff);
unsigned int one = (x >> 24) & 0xff;
unsigned int two = (x >> 16) & 0xff;
unsigned int three = (x >> 8) & 0xff;
unsigned int four = x & 0xff;
printf("one 0x%x, two 0x%x, three 0x%x, four 0x%x\n",one, two, three, four);

new = (one<<24) | (two<<16) | (ne) | (four) ;
printf("new 0x%x", new);}
```

When I enter 11123243336 for `i` and 3 as `b`, I get my hex values as `i = 0x96ff3948` and `b = 0xfffffffd`. When I run this, I get `new` as `0x96ff00fd` when im expecting `0x96fffd48`.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Beware endianess when doing this - different architectures can give different and surprising answers.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Aren't bit operators endianness proof?

Comment: Sure, but the location of the high and low bytes in a word after your bit-wise operators most assuredly is not.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan But how would this effect his code? He is not directly accessing a byte of a word in the memory. For example how could the endianness effect the value of `new`? I know that it may look different in memory but the value should be the same.

Comment: Ok, I think you may be right for this case.  Worth the mention and maybe even a quick peek at that printf() output though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really clear to me what you want to achieve but from what you're expecting my guess is that you just need to shift the `ne` by 8 bits, so:

`new = (one<<24) | (two<<16) | (ne<<8) | (four) ;`